# HTML Hex color code in ng-style not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have the below HTML, in which I change the background color of the div when a user selects one of the div from the list.

```
    <div class="myDefaultCssForDiv"
         ng-style="{'background': (myListItems.selectedId == dataItem.id? 'red':'white')}"
         id="{{dataItem.id}}" >
```

The problem is that when I change from color name to color hex code I start getting Angular errors, how can I fix this?

```
    <div class="myDefaultCssForDiv"
         ng-style="{'background': (myListItems.selectedId == dataItem.id? '#A01384':'#ffffff')}"
         id="{{dataItem.id}}" >
```

**Errors that I get in console logs:**

```
Error: Invalid template:'my div code here' angular.min.js:107 
TypeError: f is not a function angular.min.js:107
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: using Firebug or Chrome inspector can you view the page and see if there are any console errors coming up, soft CSS errors or suchlike?

Comment: I get lot of errors in console logs. When I use color code HEX value, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can to use only attribute style

```html
<div style="background: {{myListItems.selectedId == dataItem.id? '#A01384':'#ffffff'}}"></div>
```

2. You can to use

```html
<div ng-class="{'myClass' : myClass != null }"></div>
```

3. You can use attribute 'background-color' in your code

Comment: I get errors in console logs when I do first example, and 2nd one I need to have two classes for selected none selected div and can you explain 3rd how to implement?